# Path alliases not woking as expected Angular/NX workspace

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl-nx

Let me get started by saying that I have defined the paths **only** in the global tsconfig file.

Here is my project solution

[image]

My paths in **tsconfig.base.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["apps/app/src/app/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "rootDir": "."
  }
}
```

I've tried all possible alternatives for the base url and the path but I can not seem to get it right, is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure the `apps/app/tsconfig.app.json` extends a correct ts config (which extends the `tsconfig.base.json`) ? See as example https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples/blob/master/apps/cart/tsconfig.json. If so, how would you describe that it "does not seem right"?

Comment: I suggest using nx console to generate apps and libs. Paths are automatically added e.g. `"@my-org/concrete-record/shell/feature": ["libs/concrete-record/shell/feature/src/index.ts"],`

Answer (score 3):

**My problem was transitioning from existing angular CLI project to nx. During that process nx renames:**

```
tsconfig.json to -> tsconfig.base.json
```

and that's what vscode didn't handle very well. Even after restarting TS server, changing paths, adjusting baseUrl, deep-diving into extending process, etc..

After investigating multiple approaches it turns out that while running `tsc --traceResolution` all modules and imports were resolved as expected. I renamed `tsconfig.base.json to -> tsconfig.json` and **everything was working again**

What's maybe worth mentioning is that in tsconfig.json I set baseUrl to "."

```
{
...
"baseUrl": "."
}
```

Works without any extra mapping configurations or packages. Also with es-lint.

Comment: Can't be the whole story...I'm using vs code and `tsconfig.base.json` works fine. I am using  nx console to generate the paths though

Comment: @AndrewAllen how? Whats the command?

Comment: @CiriousJoker there’s no one command. nx console is  an extension for IDEs that gives full gui to generate apps and libs and maintains the ts config paths

Comment: This solution is working but I'm suspicious to side effects, what would happen to apps & libs tsconfig file?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the tsConfig does not merge objects when using base/child files. So if you have `compilerOptions` set in your main app project tsConfig.app.json, as I understand it, it will overwrite the base file's `compilerOptions`  object, including the `paths` key, even if you don't have a `paths` key in the child file.

Sadly, the only solution that worked for an app I have similar to this is to put the `paths` in all of the individual app/lib tsConfigs that are used. This does have the benefit, if you want, of being a way of allowing what can and can't be referenced in an app/lib, especially if you enforce using path prefixes in imports.